# getting selected index of listbox(c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, listbox

I have a `ListBox` with SelectionMode set to multiple. When I check the selected index using `ListBox1.SelectedIndex` I always get -1 even if I click on a item?? I would like to be able to get index of multiple selected items in the listbox.

Comment: Nobody knows what ListBox class you are talking about.  Iterate the Items collection and use the item's Selected property.  Find sample code in the MSDN Library article for ListBox.SelectionMode

Comment: Please look [ListBox.GetSelectedIndices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.getselectedindices.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `GetSelectedIndices()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Since there can be more than one item selected you have to get the collection of SelectedItems. Loop through them. Each item has Index property.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
ListBox.SelectedIndexCollection SelectedIndices { get; }
```

SelectedIndex method is used when you allow to select only one value.

Comment: In Webforms, its not this property but the GetSelectedIndices() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You will get all selected indexes in one string with this code.

```
int length = this.ListBox1.Items.Count;
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < length; i++ )
         {
      if ( this.ListBox1.Items[ i ] != null && this.ListBox1.Items[ i ].Selected ) 
              {
        b.Append( this.ListBox1.Items[ i ].Selected );
        b.Append( "," );
          }
     }
    if ( b.Length > 0 ) 
        {
      b.Length = b.Length - 1;
    }
    return b.ToString();
```